# org.exolab.castor.mapping.MappingException: Could not find the class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-6.1

what are some possible reasons for the

> org.exolab.castor.mapping.MappingException: Could not find the class com.tem.ac.droca.stlife.XtXlife ...

It crashes when it tries to unmarshall then set the mapping, however I can see the class and it is where it needs to be.  The xml seems formatted correctly and the server is aware of it at runtime.  I am using RAD 8 with Websphere App Server 6.1.

I am looking for suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: be sure about package name spelling. clean your project and try again?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Tried it and I still have the error